# Upload Image from different page

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to upload an image and insert it into the database from different page. I want to create an admin panel where you can upload an image to image sider but the image slider is in a different page. It's working when my form method is inside the index.php, but when I put it to my admin.php it's not working. I think I need a GET method?

Can someone give me idea what method, requirements to do that? I'm new to php and sql.

Here is my index.php code this is where I want to show the slide.

```
<?php
//for connecting db
include('connect.php');
if (!isset($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])) {
echo "";
}
else
{
$file=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$image= addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
$image_name= addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],"gallery/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"]);
$photo="gallery/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"];


$query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO images(photo)VALUES('$photo')");
$result = $query; 

echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("image successfully uploaded ");window.location=\'index.php\';</script>';
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/slider.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: 'fade',
        controlsContainer: '.flexslider'
        });
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="flexslider">
            <ul class="slides">
                <?php
                    // Creating query to fetch images from database.
                   $query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * from images order by id desc limit 5");
                    $result = $query;
                    while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
                ?>
                    <li>
                    <img src="<?php echo $r['photo'];?>" width="400px" height="300px"/>
                    </li>
                <?php 
                } 
                ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

here is my connect.php code.

```
<?php
// hostname or ip of server
$servername='localhost';
// username and password to log onto db server
$dbusername='root';
$dbpassword='';
// name of database
$dbname='pegasus';

////////////// Do not  edit below/////////
$mysqli = new mysqli($servername,$dbusername,$dbpassword,$dbname);
if($mysqli->connect_errno){
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysql->connect_error);
    exit();
}

?>
```

and here is my admin.php code this is where i want to upload the image.

```
<form class="form" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="image">
            <p>Upload images and try your self </p>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
              <input class="form-control" id="image" name="image" type="file" onchange='AlertFilesize();'/>
              <input type="submit" value="image"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        </form>
```

here is my index.php this is where i want to show the slide.
[image]

and this is my admin.php where i want to upload the image of my image slider.
[image]

Comment: Maybe just `copy index.php admin.php` and then it should work in the admin.php

Answer (score 1):

I solved it myself by putting the php code in my admin.php

```
<?php
//for connecting db
include('connect.php');
if (!isset($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])) {
echo "";
}
else
{
$file=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$image= addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
$image_name= addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],"gallery/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"]);
$photo="gallery/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"];


$query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO images(photo)VALUES('$photo')");
$result = $query; 

echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("image successfully uploaded ");window.location=\'admin.php\';</script>';
}
?>
    <form class="form" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="image">
            <p>Upload images and try your self </p>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
              <input class="form-control" id="image" name="image" type="file" onchange='AlertFilesize();'/>
              <input type="submit" value="image"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        </form>
```